# Alternative for Telerik's Nativescript-Ui Calender

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Is there any other alternative for using Implementing calender view in {N} + Angular 2 apps other than Telerik's Nativescript-UI ?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few Calendar libraries out there. You can search cocoapods and/or androidarsenal and create a plugin from any library you like. Or "draw" your own with fi a GridLayout. But sticking to the NativeScript-UI lib is probably easiest.